# How to select columns from main table and conditionally select columns from second table with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build a query that pulls data from a main table, and possibly from a second table depending on the values. Currently I have

```
SELECT    TOP (50) A.MessageID, 
          A.UserID (CASE IF A.MessageID = B.MessageID 
                         THEN SELECT B.MessageData ELSE NULL
                   ) 
FROM Message as A, Market as B
```

Any ideas? To be more specific, if A.MessageID is found in table B, I want MessageData from table B, otherwise I just want MessageData column to be NULL.

Comment: Any ideas?  Try ditching comma join in favour of left outer join

Comment: `TOP` is `MS SQL Server` not `MYSQL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT TOP (50)
    A.MessageID, 
    A.UserID,
    B.MessageData 
FROM Message as A
LEFT JOIN Market as B ON A.MessageID = B.MessageID
```

[MSSQL LEFT JOIN online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=cfb1c6a2eec2c4d063b07a0d72272917&php_version=null&sql_version=mssql2019)

MySQL solution:

```
SELECT
    A.MessageID, 
    A.UserID,
    B.MessageData 
FROM Message as A
LEFT JOIN Market as B ON A.MessageID = B.MessageID 
ORDER BY A.MessageID DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

[MySQL LEFT JOIN + LIMIT](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=e518fdd045e9e33a1a5e290128cc899d&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)